# Diferencia entre «prefacio», «prólogo» y «preámbulo»

Tags: significado, definiciones

¿Cuál es la difrerencia entre las siguientes palabras?

Según el DLE:

> preámbulo
>
> 1. m. Exordio, prefación, aquello que se dice antes de dar principio a lo que se trata de narrar, probar, mandar, pedir, etc.

> prefación
>
> 1. f. p. us. prefacio (‖ prólogo).

Supongo que el símbolo «||» significa «sinónimo» (aunque, en ese caso, no entendería por qué no se ubica el término tras una coma en la definición).

> prefacio
>
> 1. m. Prólogo o introducción de un libro.

> prólogo
>
> 1. m. Texto preliminar de un libro, escrito por el autor o por otra persona, que sirve de introducción a su lectura.

Quiero escribir unos comentarios misceláneos (notaciones, formato del texto, etc.) sobre varios textos «técnicos». Los comentarios son comunes a todos los textos.

¿Qué palabra se adecua mejor o, por lo menos, cuál es más común en estos casos?

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo las pautas que introduce al respecto el escritor Teo Palacios;

**Prólogo** Puede tener dos vertientes;

- Como sinónimo de prefacio, es decir una introducción que sirve para desarrollar el tema que deseas.
- Texto preliminar, donde el propio autor o un tercero hace un comentario de lo que se va a leer posteriormente. Pueden ser comentarios sobre la vida del autor, o las circunstancias de la obra por las que el escritor le llevo a escribirla.

**Prefacio** Sería una introducción al tema que posteriormente se va a tratar. Se expone algo que tiene que ver con el tema principal de la novela o delo que se desea escribir.

**Preámbulo** Algo que está relacionado con el tema pero que sin embargo, no va de forma directa, sino que va dando un rodeo antes de comenzar.

---

Diferencia entre preámbulo, prefacio y prólogo

Teo Palacios

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EE2MwvUhohw

**P.D.** Mi consejo es que te mires este video, que aclara bastante bien estas dudas, pues a parte de señalar lo anotado más arriba, te muestra ejemplos y realiza otros comentarios, como por ejemplo, cuando se escribe algo como **Prólogo**, cuando en realidad es un **Preámbulo** o una **Introducción**, cuando en realidad es un **Prólogo**.

---

Otro video algo más extenso que habla de diferentes conceptos.

Partes de un libro: epílogo, epígrafe, prólogo, prefacio, introducción...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UyYWq-TVovc

Comment: Tambien _prolegómeno_ https://dle.rae.es/proleg%C3%B3meno?m=form

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Vi ambos videos y, por lo que entendí, dan definiciones incongruentes. De todas formas, creo que me voy a quedar con "Prólogo" y dejar una sección aparte para la notación porque ninguno de los término parece incluir este tipo de contenido.

Comment: Siento no haber podido ayudarte más, es cierto que algunos autores confunden unas secciones con otras. En lo referente a "notas", que no se exactamente a lo que te refieres, existe esta página que para mi gusto aclara algunas cosas respecto a las notas y anotaciones en general.  "Las notas en un texto: la numeración, la llamada, la colocación y su composición"    https://www.alquiblaweb.com/2013/08/29/las-notas-en-un-texto-la-numeracion-la-llamada-la-colocacion-y-su-composicion/   De todas formas, ¡Gracias a ti!